# Bash doesn't output here-documents to file

Tags: bash, shell-script, here-document

This `bash` script seems broken:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "It prints ok"
cat << 'EOF' > ~/doFoo.sh
        echo 'nested script doing Foo'
EOF
echo "It never prints"
cat << 'EOF' > ~/doBar.sh
        echo 'nested script doing Bar'
EOF
echo "It never prints too"
#  Here there is no doFoo.sh or doBar.sh in ~
ls -l ~/doFoo.sh ~/doBar.sh
```

The script just prints the first message (`It prints ok`) and creates a file named `doFoo.sh'$'\r'` with the following contents:

```
        echo 'nested script doing Foo'
EOF
echo "It never prints"
cat << 'EOF' > ~/doBar.sh
        echo 'nested script doing Bar'
EOF
echo "It never prints too"
#  Here there is no doFoo.sh or doBar.sh in ~
```

@Jim L. After adding the line you told the exact output is still:

```
It prints ok
```

and nothing more.

Comment: Welcome, files that start with dot `.` are hidden, so look for hidden files, `ls -a` on the terminal, or usually ctrl+h on the file browser.

Comment: When you say only the first message prints ok, do you mean you don't see any output form the second and third `echo` in the script? (does your script never output the strings `It never prints` and `It never prints too`?)

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Thanks for your help, Im updating my question, the problem stay.

Comment: @Kusalananda Just the first message is output, it breaks on firsts heredoc.

Comment: Add this line at the bottom of your script: `ls -l ~/doFoo.sh ~/doBar.sh`.  Also, update your post to include the exact **output** of your script, including any error messages.

Comment: You didn't write your script on a Windows system by any chance?

Comment: @Kusalananda Wrote on windows but edited many times on nano.

Comment: @logan46 `nano`, like most text editors, would notice that the file was in DOS text format, and then also save it as DOS text format, not Unix text format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wrote your script on a Windows system, using an editor that saved it as a DOS text file. According to comments, you then edited it with `nano` a few times on a Unix system.  Most text editors on Unix, `nano` included, will notice that the text file is in DOS format, and then preserve this format when the file is later saved.  For `nano`, if you start the editor with `-u` or `--unix`, it will always save in Unix text format.

Since DOS text files have "crlf" (carriage-return+linefeed) newlines, and Unix text files have "lf" (linefeed) newlines, this mean that each line, when read by Unix tools, now has a carriage-return character at the end of it (invisible, but usually encoded as `^M` or `\r`).  These carriage-returns are interfering with the commands in your script.

For example, this makes it impossible for the shell to find the ending `EOF` for the first here-document, as the line *actually* says `EOF\r`, not `EOF`.

You would see the carriage-returns if you use `cat -v` on the script:

```
$ cat -v script
#!/bin/bash^M
echo "It prints ok"^M
cat << 'EOF' > ~/doFoo.sh^M
        echo 'nested script doing Foo'^M
EOF^M
echo "It never prints"^M
cat << 'EOF' > ~/doBar.sh^M
        echo 'nested script doing Bar'^M
EOF^M
echo "It never prints too"^M
#  Here there is no doFoo.sh or doBar.sh in ~^M
```

Simply convert your script file to a Unix script file using `dos2unix`, and it will be fixed, or save the text in `nano` after having started `nano` with `-u` or `--unix` as described above.

```
$ dos2unix script
dos2unix: converting file script to Unix format...
```

```
$ cat -v script
#!/bin/bash
echo "It prints ok"
cat << 'EOF' > ~/doFoo.sh
        echo 'nested script doing Foo'
EOF
echo "It never prints"
cat << 'EOF' > ~/doBar.sh
        echo 'nested script doing Bar'
EOF
echo "It never prints too"
#  Here there is no doFoo.sh or doBar.sh in ~
```

Comment: cat -v really output EOF^M . I will install dos2unix  and test.

Comment: now it prints :) Thanks

Comment: Files are ok too.

Comment: The tool `dos2unix` will fix the line-ending for you; it might be in an optional package in your distro

Answer (score 3):

Your problem statement implies that you are expecting to find files:

```
doFoo.sh
doBar.sh
```

in your home directory.  Your script does not use those names.  You will find the files you are looking for by prepending a dot to each name, as specified by the `cat` commands in your script:

```
$ cd ~
$ ls -l .do*
-rw-------  1 jim  jim  39 Mar 15 14:49 .doBar.sh
-rw-------  1 jim  jim  39 Mar 15 14:49 .doFoo.sh
$ cat .doBar.sh
    echo 'nested script doing Bar'
$ cat .doFoo.sh
    echo 'nested script doing Foo'
```

### Edit:

You indicate that only the first `echo` statement is executing, and that the script is failing in the first `cat` statement.  However, your script as posted works on my machine.  It is possible you have some non-printable/garbage characters in your file that are causing a syntax error, but are not showing up in your StackExchange post.

Try copying and pasting your script exactly as you show it above, and saving it to a **new** file:

```
cat << END > newfile.sh
(paste)
END
chmod +x newfile.sh
./newfile.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Im updating my question, the problem stay.